# (TCP) Server/Client program

Tags: c#, iphone, tcp, client

I want to write (TCP) Server Client program.
Client code should be in Objetive-C. Server side code should be in C#.

I have written some code. It is working. But the issue is; I am sending the message from Client to Server. Server is receiving the message. But the received message is looking like "Encrypted" data.

**code:**

```
Objective-C
const uint8_t *rawdata = (const uint8_t*)[@"Welcome..." UTF8String];
[outputStream write:rawdata maxLength:strlen((const char *)rawdata)];

C#
char[] chara = new char[data.Length / sizeof(char)];
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 0, chara, 0, chara.Length);
String content = new String(chara);
Console.WriteLine("Received data : " + content);
```

Please help me to fix the issue.

Comment: The issue will be with "uint8_t" and "char[]". But i don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: What data are you receiving?  Is it the same every time? Is the received length the same as the transmitted length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do the following, I hope it helps you:

On the client (Objective C) I send the data as follows

```
const uint8_t *str = (uint8_t *) [messageToSend cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

On the C# Server I don't use `char[]` I use `byte[]` and I read the data from the Socket then I convert them to `string` as follows (assume that the `byte` array is named `data`):

```
string messageReceived = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, bytesRead);
```

`bytesRead` is an integer that holds the size of bytes read (I get it from the Stream since I use TCP Sockets).

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are sending data as UTF-8, but trying to read it as UTF-16. You need to convert using [Encoding.UTF8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.utf8.aspx):

```
    var content = new UTF8Encoding(true,true).GetString(data)
```